# vscode : rearrange code for js / ts files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

How can I **rearrange** the code in a .js / .ts file in Vscode? For example inside a Class, **I want it to automatically put static variables at the top, then variables, then methods, etc.**

I tried to google "vscode rearrange code" but it always point to Prettier, which does **NOT** do that.

Now maybe this feature doesn't exist on Javascript? But for example in Android Studio (Java) there definitely is an option to do that.

Also, I'm not talking about rearranging imports, I already know Vscode can do that.

Comment: You can highlight the the static variables, press Ctrl-X, move the cursor to the top of the class, press Ctrl-V...

Comment: No way. That's peasant work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing built-in in VSCode or TypeScript that can do that. I'm not sure about any extensions though.

However, if you use TSlint or ESlint, you can achieve the same thing with the `member-ordering` rule:

- https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-ordering/
- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-ordering.md

The TSLint rule (though not the ESlint one) has a "fixer", so you can apply it with one click.