# vscode - "Implement interface" -> disable inline imports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In typescript, if I do an auto-fix on a class name with "Implement interface", it will create the methods with inline imports :

```
  getInbox(): Observable<import('../../model/Message').Interactions[]> {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
```

You can see the **import('../../model/Message'** which is ugly and stupid. How can I make it import at the top of the file instead of inline ?

Comment: Wow. Issue opened 1 year ago and still not fixed. Should I switch to Atom?

Comment: @BenjaVR also posted this question if by any chance you know the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894055/vscode-rearrange-code-for-js-ts-files

Comment: It's not really a VSCode/Atom thing, it's something that is built-in into Typescript itself. If Atom is using the typescript "fix hints", it will act exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to fix that right now, [this is an open issue in the TypeScript repository](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28165)